# Expression must be a modifiable lvalue - when setting an element of a dynamic array of fixed-length arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

In my C++ program I have a dynamic char array where each element on this array is another fixed-size array, of length `MAX_LINE_SIZE`.

This is how I defined this array inside my `main` function:

```
char (*text)[MAX_LINE_SIZE] = nullptr;
```

This array should contain some text that user enters from stdin:

```
void init_text(char (*text)[MAX_LINE_SIZE], const int lines_count)
{
    delete[] text; 

    text = new char[lines_count][MAX_LINE_SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < lines_count; i++)
    {
        char* line = new char[MAX_LINE_SIZE]; 
        read_line(cin, line);

        text[i] = line;
    }
}
```

the problem is at the line `text[i] = line;`, where VS Code says this:

```
expression must be a modifiable lvalue
```

When I try to compile this code I get this error:

```
prog20Feb20.cc: In function ‘void init_text(char (*)[256], int)’:
prog20Feb20.cc:32:19: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘char*’ to ‘char [256]’
   32 |         text[i] = line;
```

I don't understand these errors. If each element of `text` is a `char` array, why does it throws that error when I try to set an element of `text` to a `char` array?

How can I fix that?

This function is a part of a homework for which I cannot use `string`, `vector` and other classes or function libraries. I have to handle the pointer explicitly.

This is how I implemented the `read_line` function:

```
void read_line(istream &is, char *line)
{
    while (is.peek() == '\n')
        is.get();

    is.get(line, MAX_LINE_SIZE); 
    is.get(); 
}
```

Comment: You're confusing the concept of "pointer" and "array".   They are different things.   `text` is not, contrary to your description, an array where each element is an array.   It is a pointer to an array of `MAX_LINE_SIZE` characters.     Any array in C++, and a pointer (like you are defining) or reference to such an array must have their size fixed at compile time.

Comment: @Peter What do you mean by "Any array in C++ [...] must have their size fixed at compile time"? Isn't the `new` operator working exactly in the opposite direction, which is to allow to create an array of which size is determined at **runtime**?

Comment: @Riccardo, yes, `text` is a dynamic array, but what @Peter says is that each element of `text` is a `char[MAX_LINE_SIZE]`.

Comment: @drRobertz So: `text` is a dynamic array. Each element of this dynamic array is an array itself, i.e. `char[MAX_LINE_SIZE]`. Am I right?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Riccardo, BTW, your `init_text` leaks memory as the arrays allocated in the loop are never deleted.

Comment: @drRobertz yes, I think I don't need that `line` anymore, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in `text[i] = line;` the types don't match.

line is a `char*` and `text[i]` is an array: `char[MAX_LINE_SIZE]`.
That is why you get the error

```
error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘char*’ to ‘char [256]’
```

You cannot use assignment to copy a C-style string, you need to use `strncpy` (or do it yourself in a loop).

Another option is to read into `text[i]` directly with your read_line function (which I assume uses MAX_LINE_SIZE as you don't pass a length) (as @molbdnilo writes in the deleted and now reposted answer).

**EDIT: after clarification in comments**

The above answer assumed that `text[i] = line` tried to copy the read lines into `text`, but after the discussion in comments, it seems like you wanted to replace the array elements.

That cannot be done, the array `text` is not an array of `char*`, it is an array of `char[MAX_LINE_SIZE]`. That is, each element of `text` is a `char[MAX_LINE_SIZE]` and `text` is an array of `lines_count` such arrays.

The array `text` is a single dynamically allocated object, and it is not possible to replace an element of that array with another dynamically allocated `char[]`.

This also means that the `init_text` function leaks memory, as the arrays allocated by `char* line = new char[MAX_LINE_SIZE];` are never deleted.

**Also, please note** that as written, the parameter `text` is a local variable in `init_text`, so the new array that is allocated will not be reachable in the caller. That is, `text` in `main` will still be `nullptr` after calling `init_text`. (And `init_text` leaks memory, as the new array cannot be reached after returning.)

If you want `init_text` to change `text` in main, you need to change to call by reference (or pass a pointer to the pointer).

Comment: I have posted the code of `read_line` function. But why does the code works if I read directly `text[i]`? Don't I need to explicitly set the size of `text[i]` array?

Comment: Each element of `text` is a `char[MAX_LINE_SIZE]`, so you cannot change the size of the lines.
(BTW, your read_line is similar to std::istream::getline so if you are allowed I'd suggest using that)

Comment: Ok, now I understand: the length of each line of `text` is defined when I declare `text` itself: `char (*text)[MAX_LINE_SIZE] = nullptr;` and so I don't need to use an additional buffer (i.e. my `char* line = new char[MAX_LINE_SIZE];`) to read the line, because I have already got a buffer exactly inside `text` array which already has the size I need.
Thank you very much!

Comment: @Riccardo, That is correct. But (unless this was an assignment or you have very good reasons to avoid the standard library) do use std::vector and std::string instead of built-in arrays.

Comment: @Riccardo, your code may not work as you intended, see last edit

Comment: "The array `text` is a single dynamically allocated object, and it is not possible to replace an element of that array with another dynamically allocated `char[]`." "If you want `init_text` to change text in main, you need to change to call by reference (or pass a pointer to the pointer)."
ok, I've updated my code following your suggestions and now it works!

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign to arrays; that you're going through a pointer to an array makes no difference.
Also, `text[i]` is an array and `line` is a pointer, and pointers are not arrays.
Further, `text[i]` already is an array with `MAX_LINE_SIZE` elements, and you don't need to allocate any dynamic memory for it.

Your code is easily fixed by simplifying the code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines_count; i++)
{
    read_line(cin, text[i]);
}
```